# Heavy smoke taste

Tags: meat

I have a masterbilt electric smoker and my wife tells me it has too much smoke taste to it. What am I doing wrong? The instructions say not to soak the wood chips.

Comment: Using it too long for the amount of food in it? Slicing too thin before smoking? Too much wood? More details please: What are you smoking in it, how hot, hot long etc.

Comment: No need to soak wood chips or chunks, that is true.  Is it getting hot enough?  The smoke should be blue, as opposed to white.  A white smoke (cooler) will leave a much more astringent flavor.

Comment: @ChrisH It sounds like you know a lot of the reasons this could happen, and it might be helpful to just write an answer mentioning them all. That way the OP gets an answer right away, and it's useful to future readers, whether or not their issue was exactly the same as the OP's.

Comment: @moscafj same might go for you!

Comment: @Jefromi...on fire!

Comment: @jefromi I've done plenty of reading but my experience of smoking is limited to garlic and chillies in a home made cool smoker (that's still a work in progress because of the opposite problem). I was just first to suggest how the OP might clarify the question.

Comment: Knowing *what you do* actually helps others pinpoint *what  you could do better* - details, please! As it stands, this is very vague and answering can mean either listing lots of potential causes (most if them probably not the culprit here) or trying a wild guess.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered trying different types of hardwood for your smoking?  Some people dislike the flavors of particular hardwoods (e.g. I'm not a big fan of mesquite, but I think that cherry, oak, and hickory are delicious).

Also, consider this: *What* are you smoking?  In this case, size matters.  Depending on how large the portions you're smoking are, you may be able to reduce smoking time.

Comment: It's better to wait for more info from the OP, particularly if you have questions, as you seem to.